# FFMPEG: How to create a webp preview file with 16:9 aspect ratio and no stretching

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop, webp

I'm trying to create a webp file for videos to show a quick preview of them like Youtube with 16:9 aspect ratio and black/blurred background.

[image: A frame of preview file with blurred background and no streching]

*How is that possible to make something like this using FFMPEG?*

The following script is what I tried and it works, but when the `w / h` ratio of the video is smaller than `1.7711442786069651741293532338308...` or equal to it, I get this error:

**Error:**

```
[Parsed_crop_5 @ 000002438207c580] Invalid too big or non positive size for width '350' or height '196'
```

---

**FFMPEG script**

```
ffmpeg -r 16 -ss 0 -i <INPUT FILE> -loop 0 -c:v libwebp -lavfi "[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setpts=0.3*PTS,scale=350:-1,crop=h=iw*9/16" -vb 800K -t 00:00:03 out.webp -y
```

Comment: Do you want the final output to be a fixed 350x196?

Comment: @Gyan Not exactly, If the input is a vertical video, I want to add a black/blurred background to change its aspect ratio to 16:9, And then I want to change its size to 350x196.